# Reference for Non-Linear Water Waves

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, resource-recommendations, non-linear-systems, integrable-systems

In class, my professor just mentioned that some finite-amplitude water waves were satisfied by the KdV equation. Is there some reference which shows how to derive this from $1st$ principles, and also discusses other non-linear water waves?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353841/2451 and links therein.

Comment: All the links there talk about general dynamical systems, and not about nonlinear waves specifically