# Solutions to Chen System/Attractors

Tags: chaos-theory, non-linear-systems, bifurcation

I have a problem involving the new chaotic system dubbed as the Chen System. This involves a system of coupled nonlinear ordinary differential equations. My problem is to determine for which parameters a, b, and c would yield a periodic and chaotic solution. Here is the Chen System

[image]

I am given the initial condition (t=0) that a particle lies on the xyz-plane at a point (-10,0,35). I was notified that if I plugged in a=40, b=5, and c=30, the trajectory of the particle will be chaotic. On the other hand, if I retained the values of a and c, and changing b to b = 10, periodic solutions will be obtained. My concern relies on how were these values picked. Is there any sort of mathematics (analytically) that was used here? I would appreciate any help that you would render. Below is the graph for the chaotic path of the particle.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! First, let me comment on the format: The equations become much easier to read, search and edit when [mathjax](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5610/75633) is used. It'd be great if you could use it in your next posts (or even improve this one already). Talking about equations, are you aware that your system is remarkably similar to the [Lorenz equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system)? Do you have a reference for this "Chen System"? Regarding your questions, yes, there are analytical methods, but we often have to resort to numerical ones.

Comment: @stafusa Thank you so much for the warm welcome! I am aware that this system is Lorenz-like but my question relies on the analytical methods and concepts within it. I tried to read articles involving it but, it turns out that I cannot even comprehend it. Here is a sample reference paper involving the Chen System: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228827466_Local_bifurcations_of_the_Chen_system

Comment: Lawrence, since this is established theory, papers tend to be very concise and it's better to resort to books. Some recommendations can be found here: [Self-study book for dynamical systems theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353841/75633).