# Textbooks about spin-glasses for beginners

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, complex-systems, spin-models

I am a Ph.D. student in Physics attending my second year. I would like to ask you whether you know any good textbook about spin-glasses (and physics of complex systems in general) for beginners. During my studies i focused on Electro-Magnetism, QM, QFT, Statistical Mechanics, General Relativity and so on... But i know nothing about complexity and spin-glasses. I' m looking for a good book about this stuff but not to advanced for now.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0505032

Comment: Thank you very much: concise and clear note. That is what I was looking for.

Comment: You might also want to check the site's [Book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/75633), particularly on [Complex Systems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39712/75633) and [Dynamical Systems/Chaos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353841/75633).

Comment: This is a follow-up question related to the question above so I am not creating a new link. I am interested in the simulation of the Spin glass system using modified Monte Carlo techniques (I am simulating the EA model using the simulated tempering technique). But I am stuck somewhere so would like to have a new look in a structured way. Thus, do you have any resources regarding this? I am looking for a resource that talks in-depth about the simulation aspect of spin glass and explains everything with respect to it.